# Convert multiple Textareas to LI in unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unknown number of textareas. To process the data entered by the user I need to convert their contents to list elements.

Using JavaScript and/or jQuery, how can I convert this:

```
<textarea>content 1</textarea>
<textarea>content 2</textarea>
<textarea>content 3</textarea>
```

To this:

```
<ul>
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
    <li>content 3</li>
</ul>
```

I need to asign the resulting UL to a variable that is sent to an AJAX service.

Edit - so far i tried:

```
var visibleTextareas = $('textarea:visible');

var listItems = visibleTextareas.replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<li>' + $(this).val() + '</li>');
});

var text = '<ul>' + listItems + '</ul>';
console.log(text);
```

This results in `<ul>[object Object]</ul>` being logged to the console and the backend responds that it needs an UL.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Obligatory - [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var output = '<ul>';

$('textarea').each(function(){
    output += '<li>' + $(this).val() + '</li>';
});

output += '</ul>';
```

Does that work for you?

**EDIT:** `.val()` is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: cannot remove wrong semicolon after `$(this).val()` in your answer - apart from that it works perfect, thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, bit early in the morning for me here! All corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on `.each()`, the second example should help you..